# Android NotSerializableException

Tags: java, android, file, serialization

I have an object called Run, that contains 4 strings, a string[], 2 float[], and 3 floats. It implements serializable so I could write it to a File. Here's the code I use to save the file...

```
}else{
        run.setName(runName.getText().toString());
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(runName.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(run);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Run saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

This works fine with no errors, but when I try to retrieve it in another activity I get the NotSerializableException. Here's the code I use to retrieve it...

```
FileInputStream fileInput = this.openFileInput(name);
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);
    Run run = (Run) objectInput.readObject();
    fileInput.close();
    objectInput.close();
```

It causes an error on the Run run = (Run) objectInput.readObject();, and on the else in the above code. How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class named in the exception doesn't implement `Serializable.`

Change the class named in the exception so it does implement `Serializable.` Repeat until closure. If it's a JRE class or another class not under your control you'll have to review why you're trying to serialize it in the first place .